# how to deploy message queues like rocketMq or pulsar in environments where initiating connections are not allowed?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-pulsar, rocketmq

I need to publish messages to clients who run in environment where initiating connections are not allowed, but accepting connections are ok.

with rocketmq or pulsar, the issue I run into is that they all require clients (or broker, or proxy) to initiate connection to register themselves.

wondering what's the correct way to deploy them in this situation? or any other similar software that is suitable for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

what do you means "initiating connections are not allowed?"

Comment: say a client runs on box A,  and a server runs on box B, listenning on port 9001,  the client runs on box A can't connect to box B:9001. this is what I mean by "initialing connections is not allowed." basically, any application runs on Box A can't connect to outside world. however, they can listen on certain ports and let apps run on other boxes to connect to them.